# How can I redirect my form with the sum of two values and show it in a readonly input field in Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel

I am making a simple form two sum two values. I want to display the calculated result in an readonly input after the request went through. If I dd() the sum of my two fields, the sum is correct. But I am unable to pass the sum back to the view.

I searched around the web and found nothing promising. Same with the Laravel documentation.

Form:

```
<p>
<input type="number" name="numberOne" value="{{ old('numberOne') }}">
</p>
<p>
<input type="number" name="numberTwo" value="{{ old('numberTwo')}}">
</p>
<p>
<input type="number" name="calculated" value="{{ isset($calculated) ? $calculated : '' }}" readonly>
</p>
```

Controller:

```
class CalculationsController extends Controller
{
    public function process(Request $request) {
        $numberOne = $request->input('numberOne');
        $numberTwo = $request->input('numberTwo');

        $calculated = $numberOne + $numberTwo;

        dd($calculated);

        return redirect('/')->withInput();
    }
}
```

Expected would be the sum of both inputs in the readonly. But after the submit, it's still empty. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You need to load the view again. Also, no need to use `old()` functions. You can pass those values again.

Comment: after submit is numberOne and numberTwo values are there in the form ?. and you didn't passed the $calculated value to the view

Comment: try ```return view('your-blade')->with(['calculated' => $calculated])->withInput()```

Comment: I actually solved it by using session: `return redirect('/')->with('calculated', $calculated)->withInput();`. That did the trick for me.

Comment: @JohannesGrießhammer I still wouldn't encourage using `old()` function. Let's say you have 2 different forms on your site and some fields have same field values in your controller. Now, if the user has 2 different tabs opened in the browser, then you will be mixing 1 form values with the other.

Comment: @vivek_23 thank you man. I will take that in consideration. I thank all of you very much. My first question in stackoverflow, and so many cool people responding.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you use the `redirect()` function the variable `$calculated` isn't passed to the view. I think the best solution is passing it by Session. Your redirect must be something like that:

```
return redirect('/')->withInput()->with('calculated', $calculated);
```

The `with()` function is used to pass data through the session. To retrieve it in your view, do:

```
<input type="number" name="calculated" value="{{ session()->has('calculated') ? session('calculated') : '' }}" readonly>
```

For documentation, check:
https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/redirects#redirecting-with-flashed-session-data
https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/session#retrieving-data

Answer (score 0):

```
$request->merge(['calculated' => $caluclated]);

return redirect('/')->withInput($request->all());

<input type="number" name="calculated" value="{{ old('calculated') }}" readonly>
```

Comment: Can you explain that further? What's that `old` method? And where does `$caluclated` come from?

Answer (score 0):

Add calculated value before redirect,

```
class CalculationsController extends Controller
{
    public function process(Request $request) {
        $numberOne = $request->input('numberOne');
        $numberTwo = $request->input('numberTwo');

        $calculated = $numberOne + $numberTwo;
        $request->merge(['calculated' => $calculated ]);

        // dd($calculated);

        return redirect('/')->withInput();
    }
}
```